# Has Dirac ever co-authored a paper?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, history, specific-reference

Just curious. Not counting PhD theses, books, and review papers, but regular research papers with original ideas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this soft-question as off-topic because it's about a physicist rather than physics.

Comment: I suspected it might be off-topic but I don't know a good place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article on Kapitsa–Dirac effect: Kapitza, P. L.; P. A. M. Dirac (1933). "The reflection of electrons from standing light waves". Proc Cambridge Phil Soc 29: 297

EDIT (9/10/2017): Another (important) article: Dirac P.A.M, Fock W.A. and Podolsky B. Phys. Zs. Sowiet. 1932, 2, p. 468

Comment: Right, I forgot about Kapitsa, with whom he had a close relationship.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Kapitsa-Dirac paper, I have found two other papers co-authored by Dirac:

- Dirac, P. A. M.; Peierls, R.; Pryce, M. H. L. "On Lorentz Invariance in the Quantum Theory" (1942) Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, vol. 38, issue 02, p. 193 [DOI:10.1017/S030500410002185X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S030500410002185X)
- Dirac, P. A. M.; Harding, J. W. "Photo-electric absorption in hydrogen-like atoms" (1932) Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, vol. 28, issue 02, p. 209 [DOI:10.1017/S0305004100010884](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100010884)